# Как обновить кнопку?

Tags: jquery, php

На странице есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую выполняется логика (добавление записи в бд). 
Т.е. у нас есть две проверки условий: залогинен ли юзер и существует ли для данного юзера данная запись, затем в зависимости от условия подставляем кнопку либо добавить, либо удалить.

```
    <?php if(проверяем залогинен ли юзер) { ?>
        <?php if (проверяем есть ли у этого юзера такая запись в базе) { ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" id="del" name="del" value="del" />
            </form>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" id="add" name="add" value="add" />
            </form>
    <?php }} ?>
```

Вроде все хорошо, логика выполняется как надо, но как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку обновлялось и представление? Т.е. одна кнопка заменялась другой, без перезагрузки страницы или редиректа?

Пробовал с помощью jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#del").click(function(){
        $("#del").replaceWith($("#add"));
    });

    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#add").replaceWith($("#del"));
    });
</script>
```

Но как то неудачно... Наставьте на путь истинный)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то неудачно потому, что правильный синтаксис:

```
elements.replaceWith(content)
```

Т.е. в вашем случае, надо делать так:

```
$('#add').replaceWith('<input type="submit" id="del" name="del" value="del" />
```

');

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$('#add').live('click', function() {
   $(this).attr('id', 'del').attr('name', 'del').val('del');
});
$('#del').live('click', function() {
   $(this).attr('id', 'add').attr('name', 'add').val('add');
});
```

Должно работать..

Comment: Только вместо **.live()** все-таки **.on()**

Comment: Разницы по большому счёту нет